# firebase auth/operation-not-allowed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is an angular web app.

Added the screenshot of the permission page

I'm trying to authenticate mobile using firebase.

In my firebase console > Authentication > signIn Method, I've enabled the phone and saved it.

But when I try to login It throws me an error saying that 
`auth/operation-not-allowed`

```
sendLoginCode() {
    const appVerifier = this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier;
    const num = this.firstFormGroup.value.mobileNo
    console.log('num',num);
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(num, appVerifier)
      .then(result => {
             this.windowRef.confirmationResult = result;
        })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
verifyLoginCode() {
    this.windowRef.confirmationResult
      .confirm(this.verificationCode)
      .then(result => {

        this.user = result.user;
        console.log('Login Successfull')

      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error, "Incorrect code entered?"));
  }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jITY5.png]

Comment: The error means `The provided sign-in provider is disabled for your Firebase project. Enable it from the Sign-in Method section of the Firebase console.`. Are you sure you have enabled the right method, or used the right function ? It's also probably that you have to have a paying plan to use the phone sign-in method. Have you checked into that ?

Comment: Hey @trichetriche
Thanks for the response.
do we need a paying plan even for testing?

Comment: i've just now testing this link `https://firebase.google.com/pricing/`
which shows the first 10K verifications are free for every month.

Answer (score 24):

It looks like you haven't enabled the Google sign in method in your firebase console. To solve the issue do the following:

1. Enter to the firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/).
2. Select your project.
3. On the right side of the screen you'll see a panel, click where it says "Authentication".
4. Once you've entered to the Authentication menu, go to Sign-in method.
5. After that look for the google access provider in the list that appears below the header and click on it.
6. Then click on the enable button.

It is probable that you'll have to configure a secure project ID (you'll see a dropdown below the enable button). What you have to do is, enter the android and/or ios client ID from your project, and hit save. This will tell firebase that it is secure to handle sign in operations with that client.

To be able to use the phone sign in method, you need to have a paid plan active.

Original author of answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65598080/6310260

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project in firebase > authentication > Settings > SMS region policy
and allow which region you want SMS to be sending OTP in line with app visibility in app store . it worked for me