# Firebase auth/operation-not-allowed for google signin

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In React native App

I'm trying to authenticate google signIn using firebase.

In my firebase console > Authentication > signIn Method, I've enabled the google and saved it. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeLl1.jpg) to view image.

But when I try to login It throws me an error saying that auth/operation-not-allowed

```
import Auth, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-community/google-signin";

const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
const googleCredential = Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
return await Auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

And I have got error like

```
Error: [auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ The identity provider configuration is disabled. ]
NativeFirebaseError: [auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ The identity provider configuration is disabled. ]
    at FirebaseAuthModule.signInWithCredential (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:154406:28)
    at signInWithCredential$ (http://10.0.2.2:8081/src/Utils/Auth.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:84:68)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24976:19)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25149:24)
    at Generator.next (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25019:23)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24976:19)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25049:22)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25079:13
    at tryCallTwo (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27065:7)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327973/firebase-authentication-error-the-given-sign-in-provider-is-disabled

Comment: I have already enabled the google option in my firebase console > Authentication > Sign-In Method, but the issue is not resolved yet. And I have updated the image with my question, please check it. @Nooruddin Lakhani

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't enabled the Google sign in method in your firebase console. To solve the issue do the following:

1. Enter to the firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/).
2. Select your project.
3. On the right side of the screen you'll see a panel, click where it says "Authentication".
4. Once you've entered to the Authentication menu, go to Sign-in method.
5. After that look for the google access provider in the list that appears below the header and click on it.
6. Then click on the enable button.

It is probable that you'll have to configure a secure project ID (you'll see a dropdown below the enable button). What you have to do is, enter the android and/or ios client ID from your project, and hit save. This will tell firebase that it is secure to handle sign in operations with that client.

Comment: I have already done the above steps you are given, but the issue is not resolved yet. And I have updated the image with my question, please check it. @Tiago Heras

Comment: Have you added the secure project ID @Balaji?

Comment: Yes, I have already added **OAuth 2.0->Android client** in the Safelist client IDs from the external projects field and added **OAuth 2.0->Web client** in the Web SDK configuration. @Tiago Heras